# keyboard Event Listener In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events, keyboard-events

Is it possible to have keyboard event listener                   `canvas.addEventListener('onkeydown', ev_keydown, false);` like we have Mouse event Listeners

```
canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', ev_mousedown, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_mousedown, false);
```

in JavaScript.
If not then what would be the alternate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery offers a simple way to bind eventlisteners to DOMElements

and there are also eventlisteners for keyboard events here are some links

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

you can bind them to window and this should do what you want

you can also use your own method to bind events in a cross-browser compatible way

```
function bindEvent(e, typ, handler) {
   if(e.addEventListener) {
      e.addEventListener(typ, handler, false);
   }else{
      e.attachEvent('on'+typ, handler);
   }
}
```

this should also allow you to bind the mentioned types of events

Comment: can we do it without using Jquery? i can use only Javascript in this context.

Comment: jQuery is not mentioned in the question, why force an implementation-specific solution?

Comment: I also added the method i use to bind events without jQuery - hope it works for you

Comment: @Eliran Malka i have mentioned JavaScript.

Comment: why downvote? sure jQuery has not been mentioned but jQuery is Javascript - so whats the problem?

Comment: @james didn't thought it could have be you ;) does it work with the bind Event method?

Answer (score 2):

Check if this works for you.  Your sample line had the a prefix of on which is only used for IEs method attachEvent.

```
function listener(elem, evnt, func)
{
    if (elem.addEventListener)
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent) // For IE
        return elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
}

listener(document.getElementById('myCanvas'), 'keydown', ev_keydown);
```